# MySQL protection by iptables. Data was stolen

Tags: mysql

My MySQL data is losed.. second time.

I configure iptables correctly and mysql users. Users protected by static ip of dedics and only my ip for acces is by CIDR diapason.

Iptables configuring for blocking ssh and mysql (3306) port with acces to VPS by static dedicks ips.

But my data was stolen... please help how to protect my db more?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: configuring iptables is tricky after configuring test your system with nmap and see if anything else is a miss, from your home computer or other penetration tools, for known security risks. Also run an ids see for example this article https://kb.bodhost.com/secure-database-server/ especoally where you rectrict user access in the database itself not only in iptables

Comment: Another recommendation is to encrypt your tables using keyring. Also, keep the authentication plugin active and change your passwords regularly... At MySQL level, you can use the variable bind-address to allow connection only from a specific IP address.